# Unexpected behavior with Derivative and a function parameters defined via an Association

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, associations

I am confused by the following behavior:

```
ClearAll[u, i, x, y, func, z];
u = <|1 -> 1, 2 -> 2|>;
func[x_, i_, y_] := x u[i] + y u[i] + z[i][y];
Derivative[0, 0, 1][func][x, 2, y]
```

I expect the derivative to be  u[2]+z[2]'[y] and since u[2] is 2 here
that should be 2 + z[2]'[y]

Why is the result

```
Missing["KeyAbsent", 2] + Derivative[1][z[2]][y]
```

The final term makes perfect sense, but why the "KeyAbsent" message?

Comment: Try `D[func[x, 2, y], y]` which gives `2 + z[2]'[y]`

Comment: Thanks Nasser, sadly this proves complicated too because x here is a function of y and I just want the partial evaluated at x[y] not the partial of func[x[y],i,y]. I could get around that with D[func[x,2,y],y]/.x->x[y], but the expressions are complicated and I hope to avoid all that. Hence my use of Derivative. Much appreciated though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is the result
>
> ```
> Missing["KeyAbsent", 2] + Derivative[1][z[2]][y]
> ```

Heads are evaluated first.  The head of `Derivative[0, 0, 1][func][x, 2, y]` is `Derivative[0, 0, 1][func]`, which yields the following:

```
Derivative[0, 0, 1][func]
(*  Missing["KeyAbsent", #2] + Derivative[1][z[#2]][#3] &  *)
```

This shouldn't be completely surprising because argument `i` has not yet been given a value.  The way Mathematica computes `Derivative[0, 0, 1][func]` is to compute the derivative of `func` at private dummy variables, which I'll abbreviate as follows:

```
func[X[1], X[2], X[3]]
(*
Missing["KeyAbsent", X[2]] X[1] + Missing["KeyAbsent", X[2]] X[3] + 
 z[X[2]][X[3]]
*)
```

This is differentiated with respect to `X[3]` in this case. Then the dummy variables `X[..]` are replaced with `Slot[..]` (`#2` etc.) as shown above.
Finally the arguments `x, 2, y` are injected into the correspond slots.

The problem that *Mathematica* is addressing is that the derivative with respect to some variable(s) cannot be computed if you first replace the variables by some values.  Clearest example: In `Derivative[1,2,3][f][5,7,9]`, we cannot find the derivative of `f` after we plug in the constants `5,7,9`.

Hence [@Nasser's solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/257558/unexpected-behavior-with-derivative-and-a-function-parameters-defined-via-an-ass#comment642233_257558) is the way to go.

Another approach is to use subvalues to protect nondifferentiable parameters from being differentiated:

```
ClearAll[u, i, x, y, func, z];
u = <|1 -> 1, 2 -> 2|>;
func[i_Integer][x_, y_] := x u[i] + y u[i] + z[i][y];
Derivative[0, 1][func[2]][x, y]
(*  2 + Derivative[1][z[2]][y]  *)
```

Comment: Brilliant and clear as always, Michael. Makes perfect sense. I ultimately simply replaced the u as an associate with u defined via rules, e.g., params = {u[1]->1, u[2]->2} and apply the rules to the result of Derivative. I manage other parameters in the function definition that way so it doesn't add much overhead. But your clear explanation certainly helps me understand why it's necessary. Thanks!